# C++ DirectX VS2022 Template. Problem with shaders

Tags: c++, shader, directx

I am trying to add shaders to basic template from vs2022. But there is a error when I am trying to compile.

default function looks like this:

```
BasicAppasdMain::BasicAppasdMain(const std::shared_ptr<DX::DeviceResources>& deviceResources) :
    m_deviceResources(deviceResources)
{
    m_deviceResources->RegisterDeviceNotify(this);

    m_sceneRenderer = std::unique_ptr<Sample3DSceneRenderer>(new Sample3DSceneRenderer(m_deviceResources));

    m_fpsTextRenderer = std::unique_ptr<SampleFpsTextRenderer>(new SampleFpsTextRenderer(m_deviceResources));

}
```

I edited it to this.

```
BasicAppasdMain::BasicAppasdMain(const std::shared_ptr<DX::DeviceResources>& deviceResources) :
    m_deviceResources(deviceResources)
{
    // Zarejestruj się w celu uzyskiwania powiadomień, że urządzenie zostało utracone lub utworzone ponownie
    m_deviceResources->RegisterDeviceNotify(this);

    // TODO: Zastąp to inicjacją zawartości aplikacji.
    m_sceneRenderer = std::unique_ptr<Sample3DSceneRenderer>(new Sample3DSceneRenderer(m_deviceResources));

    m_fpsTextRenderer = std::unique_ptr<SampleFpsTextRenderer>(new SampleFpsTextRenderer(m_deviceResources));

    ID3D11VertexShader *VS;
    ID3DBlob* VSb;

    D3DReadFileToBlob(L"..//x64//Debug//BasicAppasd//VertexShader1.cso",&VSb);

    ID3D11Device* pDx11Device = deviceResources->GetD3DDevice();

    pDx11Device->CreateVertexShader(VSb->GetBufferPointer(), VSb->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
```

There is a error while compiling. It stopps on CreateVertexShader line and says **VSb** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: First thing to do is check *all* methods return codes (HRESULT).

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is that this line is failing to find the file:

```
D3DReadFileToBlob(L"..//x64//Debug//BasicAppasd//VertexShader1.cso",&VSb);
```

If this is a UWP application, then the `.cso` will automatically be placed into the package layout. UWPs have limited file system access, so you can't 'reach out' of the package like this. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

You must check the `HRESULT` of every function that returns it. If you can safely ignore it at runtime, it returns `void`. A good solution is to use `DX::ThrowIfFailed` which is part of the template. See [this wiki page](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

You will also find it a lot easier to debug if you avoid using 'raw' pointers for COM interfaces. Use [ComPtr](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) instead.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DBlob> VSb;

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
   D3DReadFileToBlob(L"VertexShader1.cso", &VSb);
);
```